# Unable to change the color of buttons on multiple clicks

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I am planning to build a robotic floor. My requirement is that floor will set at run time simply by applying hurdles i.e changing the color of buttons. Up till now, the color of the button can be changed by simply pressing it but i want to change it back to its previous color if I press that specific button again. I am an unable to change the color of button back to its previous color on pressing even number of clicks. If the number of clicks is even the button should not be colored but id its odd it should change its color. Following is my code

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

class butMaddFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
int x=20;
int y=20;
JButton[][] buttons = new JButton[x][y];
    JPanel mPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel bPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel cPanel = new JPanel();
    JTextArea scoreKeeper = new JTextArea();
    Container c = getContentPane();
    int[][] intArray = new int[x][y];

    public butMaddFrame()
    {
        butGen();
        score2();
        //cPanel.add(scoreKeeper);
        bPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(x,y));
        mPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        mPanel.add(bPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      //  mPanel.add(cPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
        c.add(mPanel);   
        setTitle("ButtonMaddness");
        setSize(500,400);
        setLocation(200,200);
            setVisible(true);
    }

    private void butGen()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<y;j++)
            {
                buttons[i][j] = new JButton(String.valueOf(i)+"x"+String.valueOf(j));
               buttons[i][j].setActionCommand("button" +i +"_" +j);
                buttons[i][j].addActionListener(this);
                buttons[i][j].setSize(100, 100);
                bPanel.add(buttons[i][j]);
            }
    }

    private void score()
    {

    }

    private void score2()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<y;j++)
               // buttons[i][j].setText(String.valueOf(intArray[i][j]));
            buttons[i][j].setText("");
        }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {           
        if(e.getActionCommand().contains("button"))
        {
            String str = e.getActionCommand().replaceAll("button", "");
            System.out.println(str);
            String[] v = str.split("_");
            int i = Integer.parseInt(v[0]);
            int j = Integer.parseInt(v[1]);            
            intArray[i][j]++;
                buttons[i][j].setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        //buttons[i][j].setBackground(null);
        System.out.println(e.getActionCommand() +"  " +i +"  " +j);
        // System.out.println();
        score2();
    }
  }
}
```

.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class buttonMaddness {

     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
            butMaddFrame myFrame = new butMaddFrame();
            myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Check the current color and set the other one? What is the specific problem with that? More than "I am unable to change" it looks more like "I have not even tried to find a way to change"...

Comment: This isn't Android code.  This is for a Java Swing application.  Why the Android tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the button color to its default color if it has been clicked twice:

```
 int check [][]= new int [100][100];

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{           
    if(e.getActionCommand().contains("button"))
    {
        String str = e.getActionCommand().replaceAll("button", "");
        System.out.println(str);
        String[] v = str.split("_");
        int i = Integer.parseInt(v[0]);
        int j = Integer.parseInt(v[1]);            
        intArray[i][j]++;
        if(check[i][j]!=1){
            buttons[i][j].setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            check[i][j]=1;
        }
        else{
            buttons[i][j].setBackground(null);
            check[i][j]=0;
        }
    //buttons[i][j].setBackground(null);
    System.out.println(e.getActionCommand() +"  " +i +"  " +j);
    // System.out.println();
    score2();
}
```

}

Comment: Above code will change the button color to its default color if you press the same button twice.